# Understanding callbacks to run code in desired order

Tags: javascript, callback

I was following this tutorial and it was all making perfect sense until...

```
function first(){console.log('first')}
function second(){console.log('second')}

first()
second()

//first
//second
```

then:

```
function first(){
  // Simulate a code delay
  setTimeout( function(){
    console.log(1);
  }, 500 );
}
function second(){
  console.log(2);
}
first();
second();

//2
//1
```

I get all that, but I don't understand how to then implement a callback so that it logs:

```
//1
//2
```

in that order.

I know it will be something like:

```
function first(cb){
  // Simulate a code delay
  setTimeout( function(){
    console.log(1);
    cb()
  }, 500 );
}
```

but this blows up. can someone help me see how to use the callback correctly

Comment: Define "blows up". Do you pass the callback to `first`?

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```js
function first(cb){  
  setTimeout( function(){
    console.log(1);
    cb();           // <-- calling 'cb' is calling 'second'
  }, 500 );
}

function second() {
  console.log(2);
}

first(second);  // pass 'second' as value of cb
```

UPDATE:

In case you want to use promises (as you mentionned in your comment), it should be:

```js
function first() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {  // <-- Make the first function returning a promise.
        setTimeout(function() { 
            console.log(1);
            resolve(); 
        }, 500);
    });  
}

function second() {
  console.log(2);
}

first().then(function() {  // <- 'first' returns a promise so you can .then on it
    second();
});
```

Comment: ok great cheers. so in the modern world this could be done by basically saying (and im pseduoing) `resolve new promise(resolve, reject); first().then(second())` or something like that

Comment: @TheWalrus no, it would be `.then(second)` - you need to pass the function reference, not the result of calling that function.

Comment: pass the refence and then invoke it later on? ok cheers. 
p.s. will accept answer when it allows me